# Haplololololololology!

Tags: code-golf, string

### Haplology

Haplology is a linguistic term:

> the omission of one occurrence of a sound or syllable that is repeated within a word, for example probly for probably.

For this challenge, it means specifically, replacing any sequences of two or more letters that are repeated two or more times with just one copy.

For example:

- haplology -> haplogy
- [boobook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_boobook) -> book
- couscous -> cous
- [ngorongoro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngorongoro_Conservation_Area) -> ngoro
- hehehe -> he
- [whakakakakaka](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=IIShzeI-l2IC&pg=PA212&lpg=PA212&dq=%22whakakakakaka%22&source=bl&ots=iAvoUxdspI&sig=ACfU3U2NmOv8IKilvNty_Efm8HSd5x_2ww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq_5D9k8X3AhUBH7cAHRTjBRUQ6AF6BAgoEAM#v=onepage&q=%22whakakakakaka%22&f=false) -> whaka
- [lerderderg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerderderg_Gorge) -> lerderg

If there are multiple, non-overlapping repeating sequences, they all get replaced:

- cancangogo -> cango
- yadayadablahblah -> yadablah

Only a single round of replacements is performed, taking the longest possible sequences first, then working from left to right:

- mississippi -> missippi
- mymememymemebooboo -> mymemeboo
- aaaabaaaab -> aaaab

This means the returned result can contain repeating sequences:

- babambambadingding -> babambading

It cans also mean the end result is longer that it would be if replacement happened strictly left to right:

- bababababababadoobababababababadoo -> bababababababadoo (not badoobadoo)

Any spaces or hyphens that occur between elements of a repeating section must be stripped out, and otherwise retained:

- [lang lang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lang_Lang) -> lang
- [cha-cha-cha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cha-cha-cha_(dance)) -> cha
- hi-di-hi-di-hi-di-ho -> hi-di-ho
- tut-tutting -> tutting
- lady gaga -> lady ga
- banana-cocoa agar agar -> bana-coa agar
- [who put the bop in the bop shoo bop shoo bop who put the dip in the dip da dip da dip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXmsLe8t_gg) -> who put the bop in the bop shoo bop who put the dip in the dip da dip
- [hare krishna hare krishna krishna krishna hare hare hare rama hare rama rama rama hare hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hare_Krishna_(mantra)) -> hare krishna krishna hare hare rama rama hare

#### Challenge

Write a function/program/etc which applies haplology, as defined above, to a single input string.

#### Inputs and outputs

Each input will match this regex: `^[a-z]([a-z -]?[a-z])*$`

Your output is a lowercase string containing the haplologised input. No extraneous characters.

Standard rules for taking input and output.

#### Scoring

Code golf. Standard rules and exclusions apply.

#### Updates

##### Additional test cases and clarification

The algorithm (ignoring punctuation) is:

- find the longest chunk of letters that is repeated at least twice, giving precedence to the left-most chunk
- replace those repeated chunks with one chunk
- repeat, until none left
- never allow any any letter to be processed as part of different chunks

- mamapapatatat -> mapatat (there is no duplicated sequence longer than 2 characters, so work left to right: mama, papa, tata)
- babababa -> baba ([baba] x2)
- ratratatat -> ratat ([rat] x2, [at] x2)

##### Questions

> Why does babambambadingding give babambading instead of bambading (from [baba][mbamba][dingding])?

In order of priority, the chunks are [ding], [bam]. The chunk [mba] is the same length as [bam], but [bam] occurs to its left.

> Why doesn't the "hare krishna" test case greedily take the third consecutive hare?

Because the longer [hare rama] takes precedence over the shorter [hare]

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that `lan glang -> lan glang` and `lan g lang -> lan g lang`, but `lan g lan g -> lan g`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, using regex isn't easily an option

Comment: @pajonk correct.

Comment: I think this is a really good challenge (seemingly simple, but actually hard), but the hypen rule distracts from the essential puzzle and makes it worse.  Since that ship has sailed, you should clarify this sentence: "Any spaces or hyphens that occur between elements of a repeating section must be stripped out, and otherwise retained."  It didn't make sense to me, although I understand now what it means by looking at the examples.

Comment: Fun real-world examples: idololatry -> [idolatry](https://www.etymonline.com/word/idolatry); cinnamomon -> [cinnamon](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cinnamon).

Comment: Can you confirm what the correct output would be for "mamapapatatat"? Currently, the Jelly answer outputs "mapatat," the 05AB1E answer outputs "mamapat," and the Python 3.8 answer outputs "mapapat." If I'm understanding the specification correctly, the correct output is "mapapat," because deduplicating "atatat" has the highest priority, followed by "mama."

Comment: Why does `babambambadingding` give `babambading` instead of `bambading` (from [baba][mbamba][dingding])?  Why doesn't the "hare krishna" test case greedily take the third consecutive `hare`?

Comment: @Nitrodon it's the longest (in characters) sequence of repetitions that takes precedence, then the leftmost, so first [dingding] is matched, then [bambam]: `ba[bambam]ba[dingding]`.

Comment: Suggested test cases: `babababa` (a composite number of repetitions), `ratratatat` (2x3 vs 3x2)

Comment: Actually, does the challenge even define what the correct output is for `babababa`?

Comment: ...I seem to remember an interaction establishing that `missippi` over `missipi` is a typo, but the comments have been deleted (I may have deleted mine? Not sure), and there's now an answer which seems to specifically avoid altering repeated single characters. Could the challenge body be edited to clarify this?

Comment: @UnrelatedString "replacing any sequences of two or more letters that are repeated two or more times" doesn't this mean that it's a sequence of two or more letters that is repeated? I'm not a native English, but I read it as `(\w{2,})\1+`. You seem to mean that `(\w+)\1+` is valid, and request that this is clarified. Correct? If yes, I truly don't understand the quoted sentence ^^'

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Correct. I read that as "sequences of two or more letters consisting of the same substring repeated" over "sequences of letters consisting of a substring of two or more letters repeated", but on actual inspection of the wording the latter seems more plausible... which surprises me because I suggested the `aaaabaaaab` -> `aaaab` test case on the sandbox post as a simple example of taking the longest sequences not producing the shortest result, on the premise that the shortest result would be `abab`, and it was added

Comment: @Nitrodon Indeed, there is no definition that says what the correct output for `babababa` is: either `baba` or `ba`. The challenges only mentions repetitions for 2, 3, 5. For a correct scenario, we should have 4, 8 and 9 as well. Too many unknowns. To try to have the situation handled, I'll vtc as unclear. Only the title has an 8-repetition, but no expected output

Comment: As pointed out there are some edge cases not addressed in the question which existing answers handle differently.  Once resolved this is going to take some moderator work to clean up and so I've closed this to prevent additional possibly incorrect answers from coming in.

Comment: @jonah I'm inclined to agree with you.

Comment: @TannerSwett I have updated the question to answer your question.

Comment: @nitrodon I have updated the question to clarify these cases.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Sorry for the ambiguity, I found it hard to express precisely. A chunk is 2+ letters. A sequence is 2+ identical chunks. Replace the sequence with 1 chunk.

Comment: Hmm, actually let me think about this some more. Having "babababa -> baba" is consistent with the algorithm I had in mind but yields as suboptimal result.

Comment: mamapap[atatat] does have a sequence of more than 4 letters though.

Comment: I was surprised to see that "babababa" becomes "baba" instead of "ba." Can you explain exactly what happens when there's a composite number of repetitions? Does "babababababababababababa" (12 repetitions) become "babababababa" (6 repetitions), "babababa" (4), "bababa" (3), or "baba" (2)?

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>45</s> 38 bytes

```
ḷⱮjⱮƤ““ “-”ẎʋƤṖe@€i1ḣ@ȯ
ŒṖÇƑÐḟẈṢṚƲÞṪÇ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hju2PNq7LAuJjSx41zAEiBSDWfdQw9@GuvlPdx5Y83Dkt1eFR05pMw4c7FjucWM91dBJQ6HD7sYmHJzzcMf/hro6HOxc93Dnr2KbD8x7uXHW4Haj2/8PdWw5t1TncngUyT9dOAWTczhbNhztnAwX@/8/NLC4GoYKCTK5EGAAA)

<s>Should be correct [for real this time](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hju2PNq7LAuJjSx41zAEiBSDWfdQw9@GuvlPdx5akOjxqWpNp@HDHYgeuo5Me7px2uP3YxMMTHu6Y/3BXx8Odix7unHVs0@F5D3euOtwOVPn/4e4th7bqHG7PAhmla6cAMmlni@bDnbOBAv//5ybmJhYAYQkIAgA) thanks to Tanner Swett.</s>

Should be correct [*for real this time*](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hju2PNq7LAuJjSx41zAEiBSDWfdQw9@GuvlPdx5Y83Dkt1eFR05pMw4c7FjucWM91dBJQ6HD7sYmHJzzcMf/hro6HOxc93Dnr2KbD8x7uXHW4Haj2/8PdWw5t1TncngUyT9dOAWTczhbNhztnAwX@/8/NLC4GoYKCTK5EGAAA).

It's [even less performant now](https://tio.run/##XYxNSsRAEIX3fYraCvbCC8hcpfJDumNMD0kGmd0gAxEEURcu/AWdlYiiKKbHncEg3qJykVgJkpnY1e@r19WPCv0omjYNFe/182PIqhb17JIvsGQ9u6Ll0c9htSB75o/q/Qe9RcXd6PtJfJ3yqMyrk/KYihtaHpC9JXtevZTXZO/LnLMNfbx@vm2Wedjuk9vQrrPzDbIXPGga5ON0EBHGAbQQrkL5J6G09LQc0IhskklWpjkcoTeFAAMUDsZc0jWuQeBB0kHsKQPjSQaZ8sExY9Bxb1NlzNCshz3dh1vr4VoTChMfdhKdqhhh8Pjfu88VEtzFNbdCHxGYdBVomWL8Cw)! Now designed from the ground up to handle spaces and hyphens, but there's got to be a shorter way to do `““ “-”`...

```
ḷⱮjⱮƤ““ “-”ẎʋƤṖe@€i1ḣ@ȯ    Monadic helper link: de-n-plicate an entire string
            ʋƤ             For each prefix of the argument:
 Ɱ                         create a list of, for each element of the argument
              Ṗ            but one,
ḷ                          a copy of the prefix;
    Ƥ                      for each prefix of that list,
  j                        join the copies on
   Ɱ ““ “-”                each of the empty string, a space, and a hyphen;
           Ẏ               flatten the results.
               e@€         Check if the argument is in each of those,
                  i1       get the first index of 1,
                    ḣ@     and return the argument truncated to that length
                      ȯ    or unchanged if it's 1 long and got clobbered.

ŒṖÇƑÐḟẈṢṚƲÞṪÇ€    Main link
ŒṖ                All ways to partition the input.
         ƲÞ       Sort them by
      Ẉ           the lengths
       ṢṚ         sorted descending of
    Ðḟ            the slices which are not
   Ƒ              unchanged by
  Ç               the helper link,
          Ṫ       take the last,
           Ç€     and map the helper over its slices.
```

Comment: I think this handles the string "mamapapatatat" incorrectly. When I do it by hand, I start by selecting the longest repeating sequence ("atatat"). Then it's a tie for longest remaining repeating sequence (between "mama" and "apap"), so I select the leftmost ("mama"). There are no remaining repeating sequences, so finally I deduplicate the sequences I selected, producing a final result of "mapapat." However, your program outputs "mapatat" instead.

Comment: @TannerSwett Good catch! I'm not sure how I didn't read "taking the longest possible sequences first" as literally taking the longest individual sequences, versus longest total region to be processed.

Comment: @TannerSwett I don’t see how “atatat” is a repeated string?  “mapatat” is what i would think is correct…

Comment: @Jonah "atatat" is a repeating string because it consists of the string "at" repeated three times.

Comment: @TannerSwett I had interpreted "taking the longest possible sequences first, then working from left to right" as length defined by the length of the repeating thing, in this case `at`.  So here we have `ma`, `pa`, and `at` all tied at 2 chars, and then we work from left to right, so `ma` and `pa` get deduped first, giving the final answer `mapatat`.  But it's ambiguous so my interpretation may be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 45 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.œεDü2εËyε„ -SNiÛëÜ}}Ë~y€g≠P*}Zi_1šÏJë¯]˜éIªн
```

Very slow, but should work for all test cases including those in the comments.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f7@jkc1tdDu8xOrf1cHflua2PGuYp6Ab7ZR6efXj14Tm1tYe76yofNa1Jf9S5IECrNioz3vDowsP9XodXH1ofe3rO4ZWeh1Zd2Pv/f0ambkqmLpTMBwA) or [verify some of the smaller test cases](https://tio.run/##jY8xS8NAFMf3forjRmkKOlakgzrooILgoBS9pOEaGnMhd9HeEBEHQToIOlpER63gFHFQhB6dhOBnyBeJeWd7trh493@P97/HPd6PcWJ7boHXgjAWvI5wY2n40shSXNRG11m6ot4WslT1ZJbmp7fI2t7w1I0aqH6SqN6JzM@eaH5xtzWX7Hr786N7dbmuBsPn5mdfPcjh49d7gWs7Cd6MxfT0Cl5mUeQ6AkUuj33BG7iqXo/kAV7thuWz26oj9bGIiCNi4kON8vOr8rNUvWqxh9suXFxF2GasVAdKh8UcAuo2CX3mMyrB@KQlESWUgAkoi5hOuuVGLS2qJ5CgFGVU90h5bJ3AHXqcg8LQA9sllhbUIhZWGUI3jtuko68eYdkWhPOzRkARpLFBdMagPw5pS2wHNyvAPOY1sAZ0BtNA/vJN4Ka4DJLhGZNMUUwIzPb/Wdys/A0). (Some of the test cases are slightly modified in the test suite.)

**Explanation:**

```python
.œ             # Get all partitions of the (implicit) input-string
  ε            # Map over each partition-list:
   D           #  Duplicate the partition-list
    ü2         #  Get the overlapping pairs of the strings
      ε        #  Map over each pair:
       Ë       #   Check if both strings in the pair are the same
       y       #   Push the pair again
        ε      #   Map over it:
         „ -S  #    Push pair ["-"," "]
         Ni    #    If the inner map-index is 1 (thus the right item):
           Û   #     Strip the leading "-"/" "
          ë    #    Else (it's 0, thus the left item):
           Ü   #     Strip the trailing "-"/" "
          }    #    Close the if-else statement
        }Ë     #   After the inner-most map: check if both values are the same
             ~ #   Check if either of the two checks is truthy
       y       #   Push the pair yet again
        €g     #   Get the length of each part
          ≠    #   Check for each length that it's NOT 1
           P   #   Take the product to check whether it's truthy for both
            *  #   Check if both checks are truthy
      }        #  Close the inner map
       Z       #  Push the maximum (without popping the list)
        i      #  Pop, and if this is truthy:
         _     #   Invert all booleans in the list
          1š   #   Prepend an additional leading 1
            Ï  #   Only leave the string-parts at the truthy indices
             J #   And join them together to a string
        ë      #  Else:
         ¯     #   Push an empty list instead
  ]            # Close the if-else statement and outer map
   ˜           # Flatten to remove all empty lists
    é          # Sort the strings by length
     Iª        # Append the input in case it's empty
       н       # Pop and leave the first/shortest one
               # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: It looks like there is an issue in the algorithm, as the string "mamapapatatat" should very likely output "mapapat", as discovered by Tanner Swet. Yours answers "mamapat".

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Sigh.. This challenge is so dang complex at times. Btw, your Java/Python answers may succeed for `mamapapatatat`, but they fail for `mamapapatatatat` (one additional trailing `at`) -> `mapapat`, since they both output `mapapatat` instead.

Comment: Indeed, I fixed both: the capture group regex was greedy, I made it lazy at the cost of 1 byte for each. A simpler test case was `atatatat`. Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: Actually and as baffling as it is, `mamapapatatatat` should indeed return `mapapatat` as I originally coded, not `mapapat` as we both thought after you found the issue.

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 308 bytes

```java
s->{var r=new java.util.Stack();for(int l=s.length(),i;l>1;l--)for(i=0;i<=s.length()-l;){var x=s.substring(i,l+i++);var p=java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(\\w[\\w -]*\\w)(-? ?\\1)+").matcher(x);s=p.matches()&&r.add(p.group(1))?s.replace(x,"%"+r.size()+"$S"):s;}return"".format(s.toLowerCase(),r.toArray());}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVPBbuM2EL3zKwZCs6DWlrC5UusEiwV62hYFckxyoCVaYkyRXJKKrS78FT30UqA/0S/qF/QP0iEtO7Z3gd2Q8zjDN3xDapwn/syLp2b9IntrXIAnjMshSFWuBl0HaXT5tiJfkXc111q4itSKew@/cKnhCwGww1LJGnzgAZdnIxvokaN3wUnd3j8Cd63PUyrAz1OF93t2vl9uYLV48cXNl2fuwC202JzWDbxe07xaGUelDqAWvlRCt6Gj@VxW6ua6UkWRJ3rxrpLvT/hCVXkS3eKmH5Y@laNyrmZyNsurSNnFay0nWrEtf@MhCKfL2vRWKkEz@vCwuUeD4vEtLjktbuH24eE6n2V52fNQd8LRbV75hZ1CT/M3b1zJm4basnVmsPQ6z289VrCK14Ju59lVNnOll78Lijo/3WU589XOiTA4nWUlvgelqC@D@WQ2wn3kHhPnDuMPzvGR5nm1e6nSVw1uBBrf4mEB8etNvaJ3ow@iL6XODw0A2HT4JkDhjvtfxTbQEw4gqgThAwr5UiP9SWqsW3qrZKAZy/LqLFdqO8TkeOb@3eM5KbZW1EE0B/76gnfCDyqeXpXcWjXSpHZRoTbOoQpmHeRK8XngytP98ZP06blmCKXFRocVza48XHmGdqWz@VHrFrJ///ojAwbZf3//@Q8yqfIcLiR35IA7snvpuFVGmXZkyWtHsjQG55pFILUZfDQWgejWOJOAJSSdiIN1gmw6vj4OliKihGvSbNnebQn2EGdrWsPSSkbe8GhLxbto7BCQXnofp7WS9ZND@rEXOBLuL8qOAeH4t0zAEpIlhn2aDf6LRGPTVvQT/ToalLvcYF/tEIXXhggsAqk7XkzG0Egni0YWZ2jYwSFhCAVaiDeZVhRsRmh5y9nk4b00jqI2teGAhEvAlvvN/RZ@cAPxZxo6AUtjsdlH13fGnDunyY08Jke34ScL@xHV74qRjjsBayd9pzmcBZdrIl/B8Z6feK9wTGHflLtQOB6J3YLULkj9gpbwsB8swv8)

### Explanation

This algorithm takes all substrings that exist, from longest, to smallest and checks if that one is a repetition with spaces or dashes. If it is, it takes the repeated value and stores it in a list (the `Stack` in the code) and replaces that long substring to something with special characters (`%1$S` with 1 being any number, actually) so that it's not matched anymore later on.

After all repetitions are found, the string, taken as lowercase, is actually a formattable that can be properly formatted to wrap up the replacements with `String.format`.

### Credits

- -3 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).
- -3 bytes by backporting [Jakque](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103772/jakque)'s regex suggestion from my Python answer.

Comment: Hihi, largely beating Python :D (so far, until my algo is adapted to it)

Comment: Too bad the `whakakakakaka` test case messes up replacing the `Pattern` with `String.matches`/`.replaceAll`.. :/ Nice answer, though!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen What do you mean? The test is OK, I don't see any issue. Would you enlighten me?

Comment: I need the `Pattern` because I cannot allow the code to act as if several rounds were possible and therefore I need to store `group` in another variable.

Comment: No, your tests and code are all ok. What I meant is that the `whakakakakaka` test case prevents it from being golfed to [268 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/55tdt2s9) You can golf it to 304 by removing the `.replace("$","$s")` and changing the earlier `+"$"` to `+"$s"`, though.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I cannot remove the `replace`: no test case uses it, but it would fail on something like this: `ababababdsd`.

Comment: Ah, I see. :) Ignore what I said then.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No worries :)

Comment: Since the input is guaranteed to be lowercase, you can replace the `"$"` with `"$S"` and then `.replace("$","$s")` to `.toLowerCase()` for -3 bytes.

Comment: I think the regex suggestion was @Jakque's--I didn't even read the regex lmao

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 196 bytes

```python
import re
def f(s,*r):
 for l in range(-len(s),-2):
  for i in range(len(s)-~l):
   if p:=re.match("(\w[\w -]*\w)(-? ?\\1)+$",x:=s[i:i-l]):s=re.sub(x,"{%s}"%len(r),s);r+=p[1],
 return s.format(*r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJtb5swEP6eX3GKVtW0uFK3LxNT1B8S8uEIBlsxtmUbpajq/npmk43kWLkXH89zHHcHborSmh8/nb9c1OCsj@DFphUddCyUT76oNtBZDxqUAY@mF4xrYVgoSv49kzOrbuyV5L/1TILqwFU7L14GjEfJtqw@7@sz8MNTfS4Yf4O3un4tnr9ty/dqF/aqUlwfiirkR8LYsPdy@/EQPrcPua4vylD88s87t389lJvUaRy9gfCSekj1WWr34rwykXXsUaLTVtt@eiyKzYKq1mqMnoJHZQwOdrCGwI21SU801Y4hGwFNb72dHYGlyEKgs8TTIoTRwrez9vR9aJL2tqelJ2wxW6NRZiPkoELI6pyi@DSIJLO/zkZoTFczO7qFBA6ztsr02f6jb9KmsmuAjpmGgezolBL5X6MbVLxVnHhaLo6RJ4vrrjS2E/TY46pXk4Qf7dEiJNLPbvWBLLgxQpQCGuvyf/0vDNJaGtwnt2pJzmGLdwedCb2Ak1dBGgRysz5n8uY8DngX3dySst40fLHqBQaKY7xKAi9/AA)

### Credits

- Port of [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247200/16236).
- -8 bytes, thanks to [Blue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42855/blue)
- -5 bytes, thanks to [Ivo Merchiers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86502/ivo-merchiers)
- -25 bytes, thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)
- -2 bytes, thanks to [Jakque](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/103772/jakque)

Comment: You might save some bytes with r+=p.group(1) instead of the append call

Comment: Additionally:
* replacing the 2 range calls with one n=range and call to n
* similarly replacing calls to len with l=len will save one byte

Comment: Could save a few bytes using walrus syntax for p https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/

Comment: @IvoMerchiers `n=range\n` + `n`+`n` = 10 chars and `range` + `range` = 10 chars. Similarly, `L=len\n` + 3 * `L` = 9 chars and `len` * 3 = 9 chars.

Comment: [209?](https://tio.run/##bVJtj9sgDP7eX2FVOx25C5Vu@zJVqu6HNJ3kJiSgEkBA1YtO21/vgG5pnS1@wXkeA7YTN0Vpzbfvzl@vanTWR/Bi1YkeehbqF19tV9BbDxqUAY9mEIxrYVioav41k4VVd/ZG8l@6kKB6cNudF5sg0LeSrX@w5rJvLsAPL82lYnsOh/emeatev6zrj@0u7NVWcX247YawCxsvnMZWsI96/fkUfq6f8hW@qkqCf925/duhXqWy49kbCJtU0IiRpdqvzisTWc@eJTpttR2m57RvRlVnNUZPwVYZg6MdrSHw0dqkJ5pqzyEbAc1gvS2OwFJkIdBF4mkWwmjhu6IDvQ9N0sEO9OgJO8x21CizEXJUIWR1TlF8GkWS4m@9ERrTcyyOTiGBY9FOmSHbP/RdunTsEqBtpmYgO9qlRP7H6AQV7xQnnh4Xz5Eni8uqNHYTDDjgolaThLe2tQiJ9MUtPpAFd44QpYCjdfkn/xsGaS0NHpM7NSfnsMOHhfaEXsDJqyANAnlZroW8O48jPkR3N6csJw3/GfUMQ8avvwE)

Comment: *[198 as a lambda](https://tio.run/##bVNhj5swDP1@vyKqdrqkI5Vu@zIhVfsh0EmGpCRqSKIkVQ9N21/vErrBmR22X8J7xmADfkrK2a/ffLifj@3dwNgJILHah7qhvj4GeYgSQq/o7gdtb017I/y0b2@MNpycvrftK/v8aVe91cfY6Fpzc2IMrKAxE4cgvYFe0rdq9/M5/to9G2lpYI@MUB/pPlS@ec2XnF0ghmhLAthBUl4SI6v4l1nRq/IQ@G/DTrkIiYesj5ByJfakR@9CIkHefdA20TN9UeCNM26YXhh7WlgtnIEUMNlra2F0o7OI7pzLfsGp7hpLINIOLrgZEK1kMUTdFFwWQ4qRQcw@4PuBzT64AZeeQECJzoAqgcRRx1jce435aZTZZnz0hmTIRzcDnkImx9mFtkOJ/@TVRC67JXCbuRlSAHepgP8NPEHNheYIcbl0TTxH2j6VATGRAQbYPKvNxnvXOyBZDDNsXpAj/ppIUpJ0zpev7982Kufw5n2y0Ety2eY/aV1wTxAkuQQdlQWCTrbrLK4QYIR3uxWWlO2kyQejXmhS@Psf)

Comment: [196](https://tio.run/##Rc7RCoIwGIbhc6/iRxI23QTrJBbihTgPrGYO5hz/FI2oWze1g44fvo/XPYe2t6ezw2XRnetxAFTBXTXQEM9ipCKApkcwoC1gbR@KcKMs8ZTx44a76r/@kH/MjqAbcCJHlXb1cGtJSORUygl4FcuJEl5AIWVGk0PIZpH7UgvNTUWF3yZ@vJKZha/Iv8No@0XKPL1gkrsyq1iwlg4jWvDp2rD@kzV3Wb4 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") based on the 209 by @UnrelatedString

Comment: I had to lose (=add) 1 byte because of a bug in `atatatat`.

Comment: For the purposes of this, `[\w -]` is basically equivalent to `.`

Comment: @emanresuA actually, it's not. because I need those characters, not the formatting characters I use as replacement.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 283 bytes:

```py
R,L=range,len
def f(s):
 m=[]
 for x in R(L(s)):
  for y in R(x+2,L(s)):
   S=s;T=s[x:y];K=0;X=x
   while S[(F:=(X+(X<L(S)and S[X]in[' ','-']))):][:L(T)]==T:K+=1;X=F+L(T)
   if K>1:m+=[[s[:x],T,len(T*K),s[X:]]]
 return s if[]==m else f((M:=max(m,key=lambda x:x[2]))[0])+M[1]+f(M[-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZPNjpswEIDveYq5YQpIm@2lInWPe0ly2XCIZPngBANWwEY20cLTp2O2JWta5gfzzWjsGaCfhsbo7z96@3i8pwdqha5l2kq9KWUFFXFxvoGOMr6BylgYQWl4JwfkPjCz6ZONyWu6cDhRtyuoY2M@8d2evuzOdPT8o1GthBMjbzkl54Scfx7IKRa6RHbmSrMIojTKIh5jIc7yAyliTmmR7xO6xSJviSe@kqpg/2ubdwllzLF85Gnhz02Kb/s4deycc46HtnK4Ww0O0xnW6UC2TmJf5JjTToykS29yoq3oLqWAMR/ZK@7MXnicHNmWJxU5smzL40dvlR5IRaJG9K1pTT1FcbxZqCpNKwYbwosxqLeAXc3deQugro01swtwI70E6KMRt0WCSCttOWsd7ic0am3qsPQkSuHt0orGWxDslHNe@16FfOokyuw/ewvCAq/L7MIpIOxmLZWuvf0TfkqJZdcgbBObAe/CLhuR/bFwgiorVRb4sNxwHzK0YX2qVpQT1KIWq7NqlOxqrkYABu3sVi/IQH8fYGgkXEzvf42/S9cYEy6@JpdqSfZL/Bqft7AnYSXcrHKNFhA8rO9z8Oms6MSX1dMtKetJw39GvWAIeYeVepTBC0YevwE)

A no-import solution in Python.

Comment: [268](https://tio.run/##Pc8xb4MwEIbhnV9xW86xK4VkqUyvYxZgCQxIlgcq7AQVOxFOVfPrKW6lro90r757LM/b3Z9eH/O6XkRFc@@vRkzGZ4OxYDGIvWMyA3ufIcLo4YIVBpbo15Y/i/wo/h0aCkVLQUW56KKkQ9FRTP59GycDjcKzJOw4dm8VNqz3w2adHv0OXnZsa2glK2yZJmplySnf7s88SYqMFsr3XDpOKigZtWjTXGz3JRNBdVJrkcFsnl@zBwcpbhFrSa6P6MSnWWjq3cfQQ5RRHTVj6qAZr1WuucVanTTb3grr@gM) (test cases stripped so link could fit)